# Restrict attribute access for an application in MS Graph

Tags: security, microsoft-graph-api

Our application leverages the MS Graph API to query current and future appointments for user calendars and mailboxes for resources (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Now we encounter the issue that, due to reasonable security policies, our application should not be allowed to read all attributes from a query response. For example the "bodyPreview" should be off limits as it is not relevant for our app.
Of course we could client-side queries for that but then customers would need to trust as that we indeed only request these attributes.

Which brings me to my question:
Is there any way to limit the attributes contained in an MS Graph response?

Essentially I am looking for a way to determine i.e. Application A is allowed to Read.All calendars, but the response is limited to the attributes "subject", "start", "end".

Something like running a filter query on the server-side before each request would already suffice.

I have digged through a lot of documentation the last few days but was unable to find something suitable unfortunately.

Comment: What about $select? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#select-parameter To return only a set of properties.

Comment: That wouldn't work for us as this would require our clients to trust us that we are only using these filters. I am looking for a way to restrict the attributes from being shared on request at all - essentially a serverside "select", as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't restrict the attributes, two options you could use to do that would be first is use the GetSchedule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. This only queries the FreeBusy information and if you allow Limited Detail freebusy permissions then you can get Start,End,Subject. The issue is that this still requires Calendar.Read permissions and if your using the client credentials flow that then gives you app full access to all mailboxes by default. However if you scope it down to one account https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access and then query the getSchedule endpoint of that mailbox it should restrict it to only querying that particular mailboxes calendar and the freebusy information that this user has access.

The other one is the Calendars.ReadBasic.All permission which is relatively new and currently poorly documented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference this permission does exclude the body and if its the same as Mail.ReadBasic should also excluded the bodypreview